# Jquery Mobile Listview Filter not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette, jquery-mobile-listview

I try to build a Backbone Marionette application using jQuery mobile.
I'm using a Marionette.CollectionView for generating a searchable jQuery mobile listview. I show that view by calling App.mainRegion.show().

```
return Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    itemView: UserItemView,
    emptyView: NoUsersView,
    attributes: {
        "data-filter" : "true"
    },

    onShow: function(){
        console.log("OnShow!");
        //console.log($("body").html());
        this.$el.listview();
        $.mobile.changePage("#main");
    }
}
```

At first, it only showed the plain list. Because of that, I added $el.listview().
But the filter bar still doesn't show. I found a similar question which stated that the element has to be appended before .listview() is called, but I don't know when Marionette appends the $el.

When I used Backbone only, I could simply call "append(template).trigger("create")" but trigger doesn't seem to work here.

What should I do to make the filter show?

Edit: This is the listview generated by the views render-method (with added "data-role" attribute):

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" class="ui-listview">
    <li class="ui-li-has-alt ui-first-child ui-last-child">
        <a href="#/users/details/hqpmy4j16z11bxfh9f2x" class="ui-btn"> 
            <h2>Thomas Davis</h2> 
            <div class="ui-li-aside">Age: 12</div>
        </a>
        <a href="#/users/edit/hqpmy4j16z11bxfh9f2x" data-icon="edit" title="" class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-icon-edit"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The filter bar does not show.

Comment: which jQM version are you using? can you create a fiddle?

Comment: I'm using 1.4.0 version. I'll try to create a fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I can't get the fiddle to work properly :/

Comment: The output looks valid, works in isolation on jsfiddle... without more to go on it's hard to see why it wouldn't work!!!

Comment: That output is a valid normal listview. Because it's a runtime output, it should include the <input type="search"> from the filter bar, but it doesn't. There has to be some problem with the dynamic initializing of the listview (.listview() method). Either place and time where it is called or I am missing something. I don't know what  further code I should post.

Comment: The .listview() method does not create the filter bar. When using a normal render() method, I could call trigger("create") and it would show the search bar. This is not working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. You cannot create a filter bar by using the .listview() function.
The only way to achieve this is to trigger the create-Event.

```
$("#element").trigger("create");
```

In my case, this didn't work either. The problem was that I was calling trigger("create") of the listview when I actually needed to call the trigger("create") of the PARENT element of the listview, e.g.

```
$("#this-is-the-wrapper-of-listview").trigger("create");
```

I was wondering why trigger-create worked when I had a normal Backbone-View and that was the reason.

Comment: `$(".ui-listview").listview()` or `$("ul parent").enhanceWithin()`, because the function you're using si deprecated and will removed in jQM 1.4

Comment: I am currently using it in 1.4.0 and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: it works, but will be removed later. so its better to use the aforementioned function in order not to face any issues when you upgrade jQM :)

Comment: .listview() didn't work, but enhanceWithin() works fine, so I have no reason to use trigger("create") anymore. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

When working with CollectionView or CompositeView you need to adding the child ItemView's using the appendHtml function.

```
appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
    collectionView.$el.append(itemView.el);
}
```

Here's the doc https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-appendhtml

Comment: How does that help my problem? I tried to call trigger("create") and .listview() from that function, but the filter still won't appear.

Comment: Sorry perhaps I got the wrong end of the stick, I though you asked how or when does marionette append the elements?  In a CollectionView it's done by default via the appendHtml method, which you can also override.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the `data-role` attribute from your view.

In order for the filter to work your markup for the ul elements wants to look like this.

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">
```

At the moment your view will only be rendering this.

```
<ul data-filter="true">
```

Try adding the data-role attribute to your view.

```
return Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    tagName: "ul",
    itemView: UserItemView,
    emptyView: NoUsersView,
    attributes: {
        "data-role" : "listview",
        "data-filter" : "true"
    },

    onShow: function(){
        console.log("OnShow!");
        //console.log($("body").html());
        this.$el.listview();
        $.mobile.changePage("#main");
    }
}
```

Comment: I initially had it in there but I removed it since calling the .listview() method produced the same result with or without data-role.
Even if I add it, it still doesn't show the filter bar.

Comment: I didn't think .listview() added any attributes to the element, it doesn't for me.

Comment: What is being generated from your view, can you please share it?